# React native navigation (undefined is not an object .. this.props.navigation.navigate

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, navigation, react-navigation

I have a trouble regarding this issue on react native navigation by the way I am using redux.

## Listserviceaction.js

contains webservicecall component is being imported here
import ListComponent from '../components/ListComponent';

## Listactiontype.js

contains action ActionTypes
export const SERVICE_PENDING = 'service_pending' and etc.

## listcomponent.js

the component, renders data on a list etc

## reducers

and then the reducer Part

## scenes/List.js

store binding will be done within the initial point of the application and passed down to the other application components as shown below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../reducers/index';
import ServiceAction from '../actions/listserviceaction';
import { Container, Content, Picker, Button, Text } from "native-base";

    export default class RenderList extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <ServiceAction />
                </Provider>
            );
        }
```

}

now after the component is being loaded and when i click onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ProfileScreen")} on my
listcomponent it fires an error (undefined is not an object .. this.props.navigation.navigate) any problem ? any better solution?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Include on your ServiceAction the `this.props.navigation` something like this:

```
<ServiceAction navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

because the `props.navigation` are by default on your parent component

and on ServiceAction component you will access to navition like:

```
..
goToSignUp() {
   this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp');
}
..
```

For me also was confusing before. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

for navigating from one screen to other, both the screens should be in `StackNavigator`. Can you please show your stacknavigator and code of the screens you are trying to navigate between.

Comment: How can we integrate a stack navigator on an architecture i have show above?

Comment: is the RenderList be included on a stack navigator?

Comment: yes it need to be added in stack navigator see here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

for using react navigation you must do this steps:

1: `npm i react-navigation --save`
2: `npm link react-navigation`
3: modify a top level class for your stack like this :

```
import page_1 from 'YOUR_PAGE1_PATH'
import page_2 from 'YOUR_PAGE2_PATH'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

export default createStackNavigator({
      p1 : page_1 //remember the first modified shown first
      p2 : page_2
})
```

then in page_1 if you want to navigate to page 2 :

```
onPress(()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('p2' , 'maybe other params'))
```

**Note :** you must call p1,p2 instead of page_1 or page_2!

Comment: in JS every thing starts at index.js ,  and then usually App.js called,so yes you can do this right in App.js

Comment: actually i didn't work with redux but im sure if you want use navigation,navigate() you mus first modified screens in stack navigator ,as shown there: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html